# How to change the toolbar and button size in tinyMCE

Tags: javascript, css, tinymce

I've created a editor page and i'm trying to increase the size of toolbar and button,
This is what I've tried
[image]

What i want is given below

[image]

Is there any way to do this in tinyMCE, Any help gratefully received!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, TinyMCE only accepts icons that are **20px** by **20px** in the toolbar. If you want to make a customized toolbar icon that is wider than 20 pixels, you will need to edit the ui.css in TinyMCE. Edit the ui.css (**tiny_mce/themes/advanced/skins/default/ui.css**) and change the following values:

```
.defaultSkin span.mceIcon, .defaultSkin img.mceIcon {display:block; width:20px; height:20px}
.defaultSkin .mceButton {display:block; border:1px solid #F0F0EE; width: 20px; height:20px; margin-right:1px}
```

Change **width** and **height** value as you want.

Comment: By changing .defaultSkin .mceButton class the width of button increased, but the image size is not increased by changing .defaultSkin span.mceIcon, .defaultSkin img.mceIcon class. Please check this image link http://i.stack.imgur.com/ax2iw.png

Comment: @bios:  You must resize the **icons.gif** image (tiny_mce/themes/advanced/img/icons.gif) too.

Comment: Please tell me how to resize that background image

Comment: @bios: You can using image editor program. Like Adobe Photoshop, Microsoft Office Picture Manager, etc.

Answer (score 0):

**JQuery Approach :**
When you execute the following instruction on console browser,

```
$('a[role=button]')
```

You will have 20px 
So ,you can do the following instructions :

```
$('a[role=button],img.mceIcon,span.mceIcon').css({'width':'30px','height':'30px'})
$('img.mceIcon,span.mceIcon').css('margin','2px')
```